# A simple doubt on Clausius-Clapeyron equation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, phase-transition

Blundell and Blundell writes
$$ 
\frac{\mathrm{d} p}{\mathrm{~d} T}=\frac{s_{2}-s_{1}}{v_{2}-v_{1}}$$ where $s_1$,$s_2$ are the entropy per particle in phase 1 and 2  and $v_1$,$v_2$ are the entropy per particle in phase 1 and 2

If we define latent heat per particle as $l=T \Delta s,$ we then have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} p}{\mathrm{~d} T}=\frac{l}{T\left(v_{2}-v_{1}\right)}$$  **or equivalently**
$\frac{\mathrm{d} p}{\mathrm{~d} T}=\frac{L}{T\left(V_{2}-V_{1}\right)}$
This is the Clausius-Clapeyron equation.

How can we go from the second equation to the third? How did the author change the specific quantities to absolute ones?

**Edit**: Many comments say that just multiply it by the number of moles and you'll get the final equation. But in order to get the final equation I've to multiply  $v_1$ by $n_1$ and $v_2$ by $n_2$  ,where  $n_1$ and $n_2$ refer to the number of moles in each phase.
That can't be achieved by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the same term.

Comment: I thought some multiplication of a quantity will do that, also because the text doesn't talk about it means it's trivial and only I'm failing in understand it.

Comment: If you multiply the numerator and denominator of the fraction by the same quantity, you get the same ratio. Use the number of particles, and you have done.

Comment: @GiorgioP, if we multiply by the same quantity, say the number of particles we won't get the last expression.

Comment: Yes we do $\uparrow$, that's the way [extensive quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties#Extensive_properties) work.

Comment: You just multiply numerator and denominator by the number of moles that change from liquid to vapor.

Comment: @Chet Miller, thank you but But in order to get the final equation I've to multiply  $v_1$ by $n_1$ and $v_2$ by $n_2$ and that can't be achieved by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the same term.

Comment: @Urb,please see the edit of my question.

Comment: $n_1=n_2$ because both numbers refer to the atoms *changing phase*, not the total number of each phase present.

Comment: @Mike stone,Thank you. Since Clausius clapeyron equation is applied at the equilibrium,at the coexistence between two phases, therefore there aren't any net number of atoms that change phase, imho.

Comment: Exactly!  $s_1-s_2$ is the change of entropy when 1 particle changes phase and $l$  is the latent heat for 1 particle to change phase. So what one phase gains the other loses, so there is no change in total number.  if $N$ particle change phase then $Ns_1-Ns_2$ is the change in entropy, and $Nl$ is the latent heat. It's the  *same* $N$  in each factor

Comment: I'm not quite getting it, I'll study all the responses again. And thank you dear mike stone.